# error al instalar Docker Desktop 4.20.1 "Se denegó el acceso a la clave de Registro"

Tags: docker

Les comparto el error completo al intentar instalar

Component CommunityInstaller.AutoStartAction failed: Se denegó el acceso a la clave de Registro 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'.
en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__30.MoveNext()
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en CommunityInstaller.InstallWorkflow.d__23.MoveNext()

Comment: Tenes permisos de administrador?

Comment: es tu antivirus, dado que es la seccion de los registros que auto inicia programas!